# Subclassing UIWindow - Need Preprocessor Help

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, subclass, uiwindow

Yes, I know subclassing UIWindow is frowned upon, but my subclassed UIWindow is for debugging purposes only (it takes a  screenshot of the current-page once a specific motion event is detected).

Anyway, I made a custom precompiler flag called `DEBUG` in my project's *Build Settings*, but I'm having a problem getting it to load/function properly. Right now, it's not taking the screenshot, but it is registering the occurrence of the motion event.

Here's the code I have in the AppDelegate's  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
#if DEBUG
    DebugWindow *debugWindow = [[DebugWindow alloc] init];
    self.window = debugWindow; //'window' is declared in the AppDelegate's @interface file and synthesized as window=_window in the @implementation file  
#else
    self.window = _window;
#endif

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: how did you make the custom custom precompiler flag called DEBUG in your project's Build Settings?

Comment: I went to the project name, Build Settings tab, click, add Build Setting, and named it DEBUG. I then opened up the tree it created and set `debug` to `YES` and `release` to `NO`.

Comment: I'm going to post a screenshot and some of my code to help you understand in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to use debug flag

```
#if DEBUG == 1
#define CMLog(format, ...) NSLog(@"%s:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[NSString stringWithFormat:format, ## __VA_ARGS__]);
#define MARK    CMLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
#define START_TIMER NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
#define END_TIMER(msg)  NSTimeInterval stop = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]; CMLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Time = %f", msg, stop-start]);
#else
#define CMLog(format, ...)
#define MARK
#define START_TIMER
#define END_TIMER(msg)
#endif
```

And here is the screenshot

[image]

Also in the release setting put the flag to 0
Like this -DDEBUG=0

This way you can achieve what you want to achieve.Let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll look at it in depth this weekend, and give you the answer-checkmark once I get it working! Otherwise, I'll come back here with a question or two :)

Comment: Had a moment to look it over right now. I can't find that window you're looking at in Xcode 4.0.2, nor 4.2. I checked under Build Settings in my target app.

Comment: You need to set flag in build settings it might be at different place in xcode 4. Mine is 3.2.5 so search on google for it or stack overflow you will find the place where this setting need to be set. You can give reference of my answer for more explanation.